# Java separate class initialization in loop

Tags: java, loops

I'm writing a program that reads a text files which has blocks of queries that we then put into a directed graph that represents the persons internet activity for that block for example

BLOCK 1

reddit.com
reddit.com/r/CS

this would create a tree with one root and one node with the first line being the root.

My issue is that I have a class called breakApart to which reads the text file and create a separate tree for each block and fills it. I'm not going to post the full code, but I will post exactly where the issue with initialization is factoring in.

CODE

```
while (thisLine != blank && thisLine != null)//loop for text block
                 {
                  if (thisLine.equals(blank))
                  {
                      if (thisLine.startsWith("(http") || thisLine.startsWith("http")) //ROOT NODE CREATION, THUS NEW BreakApart class to make new tree
                         {
                            BreakApart ba = new BreakApart(new MyGraph());
                            ret = ba.breakApart(thisLine);
                            OVA.put(ret.t, ret.u);
                            l.add(ret.t);
                         }
                  }

                else
                 {
                     if (thisLine.startsWith("(http")||thisLine.startsWith("http")) //LEAF CREATION, we only want to add to breakapart instanciated about
                     {
                        ret = ba.breakApart(thisLine); //This line is the issue it says ba is not initilized, but the way the file is implemented a root is always firs
                        OVA.put(ret.t, ret.u);
                        l.add(ret.t);
                     }
                 }

                     thisLine = reader.readLine();
                 }
```

The issue is the we need to have an if else or some conditional in this while that creates a new BreakApart class(contains tree) when a read in line is a root, and we need to simple add to that tree when it is a leaf. But as you see, ba says it is not initialized in the leaf section. Also we tried making it a class variable, but that did not work.

Comment: This is a bit *too* simplified.  The logic is simple; `ba` doesn't exist in the scope of your other `if` block because it's not defined there.  Also, this logic seems a bit strange - you check to see if the line is equal to some `blank` variable, but if it *isn't*, you're looking to see it start with something?  It almost feels like you're duplicating logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the declaration of the `ba` variable above the loop so that it is known in the `else` statement.

```
BreakApart ba = null;
while (thisLine != blank && thisLine != null)//loop for text block
```

Answer (score -1):

Please move the line

```
BreakApart ba = new BreakApart(new MyGraph());
```

before the line

```
while (thisLine != blank && thisLine != null)
```

---

The `ba` you are trying to access is not intialized, as you are doing the class instantiation in a separate scope. If you put it before the mentioned line you will create a variable that is accessible in all upcoming "child"-scopes.

Comment: this will recreate ba with every loop iteration. I guess this is not what he wants. put BreakApart ba = null; exactly where JDC set. Initialize it where you want and beware of possible null pointer in your else as ba is only initialized if the line equals "blank" and starts with http and so on...

Comment: I had that originally, but it did not create the graphs for me as I expected. I'm beginning to think that i may have a logic error elsewhere in the code. when i put BreakApart ba = null - my graph is never built and it prints a size of 0. Thanks for the suggestions though! will keep working in it.